# How to pass a value if its null ,if its not null then .toDate() it

Tags: javascript, typescript, fullcalendar-4

I am trying to pass a date value into the rrule plugin of a fullCalendar as follows

```
Endate = null;

rrule: {
        freq: "Daily",
        interval: 1,
        dtstart: StartDate.toDate(),
        until: EndDate.toDate()
                        
        }
```

in my EndDate as you can see i am formatting it to .toDate().

But now my EndDate can also be **null** so that would fail when i pass it to be formatted to .toDate()

My question is if my endDate is null how can i have that value be passed in as just null and if i have a value then i can .toDate() it

i tried something like this

`until: EndDate == ?? || EndDate.toDate()`  // so if its null pass that value or pass the value if its not null

But the above doesnt work.

i tried this

```
until:EndDate === null ? null:EndDate.toDate() // this works but is there a cleaner way to do it instead of reassigning endDate to null?
```

Comment: No, there's not a cleaner way to do it other than what you got to work.

Comment: @Russ okay, i was just thinking it looks a bit messy

Comment: What about `EndDate ? EndDate.toDate() : null`

Comment: What kind of magic do you expected?

Answer (score 1):

I think [Optional Chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) is what you're looking for.

`endDate?.toDate()` will attempt to call the toDate method and return undefined if endDate is null.

If you need `until` to be null and not undefined, you can use `endDate?.toDate() ?? null` instead

Answer (score 1):

You can use the optional chaining operator `EndDate?.toDate()`

https://codepen.io/niklhs/pen/oNzdaGw?editors=1111

It will not throw an error if `EndDate` is either `undefined` or `null`.
Instead it will return `undefined`.